# Tailwinds + Ant design : Button color is white but has own color wnen I hover it

Tags: next.js, antd, tailwind-css

I applied the tailwind CSS and Ant design with my Next.js project.

I found the primary button got a white color.

[image]

But it shows own primary button color when the mouse over.

[image]

global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
    h1 {
      @apply text-2xl;
    }
    h2 {
      @apply text-xl;
    }

    /* ... */
  }


@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

Home.module.css

```
.container {
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 2rem 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}



.footer a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.title a {
  color: #0070f3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.title a:hover,
.title a:focus,
.title a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

.title,
.description {
  text-align: center;
}

.description {
  margin: 4rem 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.code {
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono,
    Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.card {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: color 0.15s ease, border-color 0.15s ease;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.card:hover,
.card:focus,
.card:active {
  color: #0070f3;
  border-color: #0070f3;
}

.card h2 {
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.card p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.logo {
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

JSX code is like the following.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button, Table } from "antd";
import FishbowlLayout from "../../components/FishbowlLayout";

export function Index() {
  

  return (
    <div>
      # FishbowlLayout uses Layout from Ant design.
      <FishbowlLayout>. 
        <div className="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4">

          # Button
          <Button className="col-end-6 col-span-1 ..." type="primary">
            New project
          </Button>

          # Table
          <div className="col-span-5 ">
            <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />;
          </div>
        </div>


      </FishbowlLayout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: Can you share the  react code where you're inserting this button component in your page?

Comment: I added my JSX code too.

Comment: You can simply use tailwind components  from `taiblocks` https://tailblocks.cc/ or from `flowbite` https://flowbite.com/docs/components/buttons/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your tailwind.config file add the following:

```
corePlugins: {
    preflight: false
}
```

it's explained in a lot more detail in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oG6XPy1t1KA&ab_channel=TailwindLabs

edit: typo, thanks for pointing it out Fabio

Comment: You should not use camelCase:

`preflight: false`

and it works fine. Thank you for the tip

Comment: It will not work if you upgrade an existing project

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me but it doesn't affect other things?

Comment: It may help for new projects. But it breaks some default styles of tailwind. And if you implement it on ongoing project you should check all you components.

Answer (score 5):

I also encounter the question recently, after deeper investigation, I think it is better resolve by **postcss plugin**, So I created the plugin [`postcss-antd-fixed`](https://github.com/yunsii/postcss-antd-fixes).

It will add **excluded pseudo class** for button related selectors now from tailwind [preflight.css](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/src/css/preflight.css)

For example, Transform the code

```css
button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}
```

to

```css
button:where(:not([class^="ant"])),
[type='button']:where(:not([class^="ant"])),
[type='reset']:where(:not([class^="ant"])),
[type='submit']:where(:not( [class^="ant"])) {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Online example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/postcss-antd-fixes?file=postcss.config.js

It make **antd + tailwindcss** works smoothly, at least for me.

Moreover, the plugin support custom `prefixCls` and `hashPriority`, check out type definition about [`PluginCreator<{ prefixes?: (string | PrefixItem)[] }>`](https://github.com/yunsii/postcss-antd-fixes/blob/2791f68ea0be432761199750280be42dfb575ef5/src/plugin.ts#L11)

Comment: My "Ok" button background for date picker from ant-design was transparent because of tailwind base styling; your plugin solved this issue. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Interesting.  Preflight is a set of base styles that Tailwind applies, and it is setting the button background color to transparent.

The solution is to disable Preflight in tailwind.config.js; see the [Tailwind documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to override the CSS as shown below:

```css
.ant-btn:not([disabled]):hover {
    background:#faad14 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[One CLS-related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179489/4892968) (Cumulative Layout Shift) thing also resolves the transparent button issue;

(code below is originally taken from the linked solution, but was then changed a little)

Store this component as separate file.

```js
'use client';
import { type PropsWithChildren, useState } from 'react';
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation';
import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';

export const AntdRootStyleRegistry = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
  const [cache] = useState(() => createCache());

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    return (
      <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `</script>${extractStyle(cache)}<script>`,
        }}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <StyleProvider cache={cache} ssrInline hashPriority={'high'}>
      {children}
    </StyleProvider>
  );
};
```

And then put the component under your `antd`'s ConfigProvider. I also use a separate file for it:

```js
import { type PropsWithChildren } from 'react';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';
import { antdThemeConfig } from '@/app/antdThemeConfig'; // it's where you store your Antd theme config
import { AntdRootStyleRegistry } from '@/app/[locale]/AntdRootStyle';

export function AntdProviders({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75867259/next-js-13-with-ant-design-5-components-and-pages-render-before-styles-load-ca
  return (
    <ConfigProvider theme={antdThemeConfig}>
      <AntdRootStyleRegistry>{children}</AntdRootStyleRegistry>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

This provider should wrap your entire antd application.

Answer (score 0):

Short term solution:
For example:  I am using antd primary button on my code like:

```
<Button type="primary">Click me</Button>
```

Now go to your main/root css file (globals.css in my case) and add:

```
.ant-btn-primary:not([disabled]) {
  background:#1677ff !important;
}
.ant-btn-primary:not([disabled]):hover {
  background:#1f4ce0 !important;
}
```

The button color starts appearing.
Note: to get classNames, kindly go to antd official button docs and hover on button you want and grab it. Each button type has unique className like `antd-btn-dangerous` and `antd-btn-primary`.
I faced same issue and the correct answer choosen by you that uses `preflight: false` has too much risk. I tried that and my whole codebase styling fusked up badly that i had to revert it. Happy Coding!