# PrimeVue + Tailwind conflict: Button background missing

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, primevue

I start with a relatively fresh Vue3 + PrimeVue + Tailwind setup.
My problem is that the PrimeVue button does not display correctly when I add Tailwind.

To test this, please have a look at the following [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-primevue-tailwind-repo-dljqpf?file=/src/main.ts).
As soon as the `tailwind.css` is commented out in the `main.ts`, the PrimeVue button is displayed correctly again.
And also only "primary" buttons are affected.

Can you please help me to display the PrimeVue buttons correctly together with Tailwind?

Comment: I think you're supposed to use PrimeFlex with PrimeVue

Comment: corePlugins: { preflight: false } [Answered in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715157/tailwinds-ant-design-button-color-is-white-but-has-own-color-wnen-i-hover-it)

Answer (score 3):

Interesting. Preflight is a set of base styles that Tailwind applies, and it is setting the button background color to transparent.

If you’d like to completely disable Preflight — perhaps because you’re integrating Tailwind into an existing project or because you’d like to provide your own base styles — all you need to do is set preflight to false in the corePlugins section of your tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
      corePlugins: {
        preflight: false,
      }
    }
```

[Answered in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715157/tailwinds-ant-design-button-color-is-white-but-has-own-color-wnen-i-hover-it)

Answer (score 2):

The Tailwind CSS seems to be setting the button background to transparent.

I moved its CSS to just before the Prime import in your example (main.ts), which fixed the missing background problem.

However, I don't know if this might have other unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks for testing. I now use both 'mdc-indigo' themes and there the error did not occur. My second idea was to create an own "primary" button with the Taiwind classes.

Answer (score 2):

PrimeVue docs says you should wrap the base and utilities in separate layers and make sure primevue layer comes after the base.

So in your main.css it will look like this:

```
@layer tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities;

@layer tailwind-base {
    @tailwind base;
}

@layer tailwind-utilities {
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
}
```

Source: https://primevue.org/csslayer/#tailwind