# Nuxt module: How can I use Tailwind without breaking PrimeVue's pre-defined style

Tags: javascript, css, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, primevue

**Brief**: I'm trying to start a Nuxt.js project with both Tailwind CSS and PrimeVue installed as modules. And I would like to use pre-styled PrimeVue (aka. `unstyled: false`). However, Tailwind seems to break PrimeVue's pre-defined style.

**Problem**: Before adding `@nuxtjs/tailwindcss` as a Nuxt module, every PrimeVue components works fine (pic.1, pink). However, after adding it the color of every PrimeVue components gets "infected" (pic.2, blue & dark). I've tried changing PrimeVue's theming but it didn't work. How can I use both without Tailwind breaks PrimeVue?

[image: before adding tailwind module]
[image: after adding tailwind module]

**Config file: `nuxt.config.ts`**

```js
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: [
    "nuxt-primevue",
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',  // <-- add or delete this line
  ],
  primevue: {
    options: {
      unstyled: false,
    },
    importPT: { as: 'Tailwind', from: 'primevue/passthrough/tailwind' },
    cssLayerOrder: 'tailwind-base, primevue, tailwind-utilities',
  },
  css: [
    'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-pink/theme.css',
    'assets/main.css'
  ]
})
```

**The Vue source code `app.vue`**:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <Button>uwu</Button>
    <InputText v-model="value" placeholder="Search" />
    <div class="w-10 h-10 bg-slate-500">a</div>
    <div class="w-10 h-10 bg-primary-500">a</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const value = ref("");
</script>
```

**Complete Project Source Code**: https://github.com/Saplyn/nuxt-tailwind-primevue/tree/8427c5067063fd86614ee1fbe12acc8fa909eba5 (a just-started-up project)

**I've Tried**:

- [Follow along the **official PrimeVue** getting started guide](https://primevue.org/nuxt/), no use. However, I noticed that:

  - removing `importPT: { as: 'Tailwind', from: 'primevue/passthrough/tailwind' }` from the `nuxt.config.ts` may restore some of the styled effects (no longer "infected", has a pink border on focus), though most of the style get lost.
  - removing `'primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-pink/theme.css'` from the `nuxt.config.ts` does not get ride of the "infection".
- [Follow along the **PrimeVue Tailwind** getting started guide](https://tailwind.primevue.org/installation). But the guide looks vague and unclear, I only managed to get the primary color works (the boxed a in green in pic.2).
- [Changing the order of modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73371143/21117414), no use. It's still "infected".
- [Disabling Tailwind preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74176978/21117414), no use, still "infected".

**Last but not least**: I'm not sure if this should be an Issue at GitHub or not, so I decided to ask for help at here first. Also, if this should become an Issue, which repo should it belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I found [shinekyaw's nuxt3-primevue-tailwind-starterkit](https://github.com/shinekyaw/nuxt3-primevue-tailwind-starterkit), which somehow works perfectly fine.

I made a [modified version of it](https://github.com/Saplyn/nuxt-tailwind-primevue) which only contains Nuxt.js 3, PrimeVue (styled) and Tailwind CSS.

I still don't know how to fix it, but it's somehow working, and I'm not complaining.