# Tailwind CSS with ant design not works

Tags: tailwind-css, antd

I'm using tailwind CSS with ant design in next js project. When I use ant components,sometimes components style look wired and sometimes ant components doesn't appear when I use tailwind CSS. I have also disabled preflight of tailwind CSS but doesn't work. Please answer this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71715157/tailwinds-ant-design-button-color-is-white-but-has-own-color-wnen-i-hover-it Please check on this link.