# Next.js 13 with Ant Design 5: Components and Pages Render Before Styles Load, Causing Jump

Tags: reactjs, configuration, antd, next.js13

I followed the antd and nextjs doc to config the project.

Added this code into the `./scripts/genAntdCss.tsx` file:

```
import { extractStyle } from '@ant-design/static-style-extract';
import fs from 'fs';
const outputPath = './public/antd.min.css';
const css = extractStyle();
fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, css);
```

and this is App.tsx file:

```
import { StyleProvider } from '@ant-design/cssinjs';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import '../public/antd.min.css';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <StyleProvider hashPriority='high'>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </StyleProvider>
  );
}
```

these commands added to `package.json` file:

```
"predev": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.node.json ./scripts/genAntdCss.tsx",
"prebuild": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.node.json ./scripts/genAntdCss.tsx"
```

Do you have any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 15):

I found a way to solve it but I had to use the new "app", "layout" and "use client" features of NextJS 13.

Well, I've found the link below where chunsch added an example in the NextJS repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/44015/files

Also, @kiner-tang helped us to fix the layout shift while loading
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/42275#issuecomment-1555805914

It's possible but we need to do some weird stuff with the new `cssinjs` AntD 5 feature and with the NextJS 13 app and layout features. I would like to avoid using that but it's the way I found. Sorry.

I basically had to use the new "app" directory (experimental feature yet), create a root layout (layouts are one of the new features too), and create a RootStyleRegistry component specifying that it should be a client component with the 'use client' directive. Additionally, if you use the `Layout` component, you should specify the `hasSider={true}` prop to avoid a shifting effect in the first render.

**Install @ant-design/cssinjs if you don't have it installed**

1. Create the `RootStyleRegistry` component

   ```js
   // located at src/modules/shared/components/root-style-registry/index.tsx in my case

   'use client'
   import { useState, type PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
   import { useServerInsertedHTML } from 'next/navigation'
   import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from '@ant-design/cssinjs'

   export const RootStyleRegistry = ({ children }: PropsWithChildren) => {
     const [cache] = useState(() => createCache())

     useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
       return (
         <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
             __html: `</script>${extractStyle(cache)}<script>`,
           }}
         />
       )
      })

      return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>
   }
   ```
2. Create the layout for the root page

   ```js
   // src/app/layout.tsx
   import type { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'
   import { RootStyleRegistry } from '../modules/shared/components/root-style-registry'

   export default function RootLayout({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
     return (
       <html lang="es">
         <head />
         <body>
           <RootStyleRegistry>{children}</RootStyleRegistry>
         </body>
       </html>
     )
   };
   ```
3. Create your page component using the 'use client' directive. Remember you must name it 'page' now (like an index file inside a folder)

   ```js
   // src/app/page.tsx

   'use client'
   import React, { Button, Card, Space, Typography } from 'antd'

   export default function Home() {
     return  <Button type="primary">Ant Design Button</Button>
   }
   ```
4. If you use the `Layout` component and you are experimenting a navbar shift while loading, you should explicitly specify the 'hasSider' prop

   ```js
   // src/app/components/layout.tsx

   export function MyLayout({ children }) {
     return (
       <Layout hasSider>
         <Sider>
           {children}
         </Sider>
       </Layout>
     )
   }
   ```

I also answered here:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/38555#issuecomment-1535788843

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with next.js version 13.4.8 using a slightly modified version of [Chemah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76179489/)

Below is my code with the updates to Chemah's answer in comments:

1. In the code below, use an object with children of type React.ReactNode instead of PropsWithChildren

   ```
   "use client";
   import { useState } from "react";
   import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation";
   import { createCache, extractStyle, StyleProvider } from "@ant-design/cssinjs";

   export const RootStyleRegistry = ({
     children,
   }: {
     children: React.ReactNode;  
   }) => {                    //Use ReactNode instead of PropsWithChildren
     const [cache] = useState(() => createCache());

     useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
       return (
         <script
           dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
             __html: `</script>${extractStyle(cache)}<script>`,
           }}
         />
       );
     });

     return <StyleProvider cache={cache}>{children}</StyleProvider>;
   };
   ```
2. In the layout also use React.ReactNode

   ```
    export default function RootLayout({
      children,
    }: {
      children: React.ReactNode;
    }) {
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <body>
            <RootStyleRegistry>{children}</RootStyleRegistry>
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me following the instructions in the AntD docs, which it looks like you're doing.

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#server-side-render-ssr

Make sure you are installing the necessary dependencies

```
npm install ts-node tslib --save-dev
```

and adding the `tsconfig.node.json`, you didn't specify that you did these two steps.

Answer (score 0):

https://mobile.ant.design/guide/ssr

```
// next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['antd-mobile'], // or ['antd']
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// src/app/layout.tsx
'use client'
....
export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props) {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => {
setLoading(true)
}, [])
return (
<html lang='en'>
  <head {...metadata} />
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <main className={loading ? '' : 'hidden'}>{children}</main>
  </body>
</html>
)
}
```